# Remove from array if the parsed data is empty

Tags: javascript

I have five parsed session storage which i combine when i click save button, the problem is i can't combine all if one of the parsed data is empty, it throws an error.

How to remove if one of them is empty? Is there any method that don't need to check it one by one.
Here's my code.

```js
const d1 = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('data1'));
const d2 = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('data2'));
const d3 = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('data3'));
const d4 = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('data4'));
const d5 = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('data5'));

const ArrayConcatSession = [...d1, ...d2, ...d3, ...d4, ...d5];
```

Comment: so all d1,d2,d3,d4,d5 should contain a value for concat to happen?

Comment: Checkout filter Array prototype.

Comment: @cmgchess not required to contain value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can initialize each data variable to an empty array if the corresponding session storage data is empty:

```
const d1 = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('data1')) || []; // initialize empty array if data is empty
....
....
const d5 = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('data5')) || [];
```

Then apply the `filter()` method to remove any null values from the array.

```
const ArrayConcatSession = [...d1, ...d2, ...d3, ...d4, ...d5].filter(data => data !== null);
```

Comment: You can actually remove the '! == null'

Comment: It's depend on the data type. If data is Number, dont replace '!== null' by boolean casting as 0 will be cast to false.